# Django 'settings' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

this is my first python project. I am having issues setting up a project someone else has written. I am getting the following `'Settings' object has no attribute 'FOXYCART_URL'` here's the stack trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'chunks',
 'staging',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'FOXYCART_URL'
```

I was wondering where do I need to set the `FOXYCART_URL` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are using an app called django-foxycart, but don't have it fully set up, yet something in your project is importing and wanting to use it.

There is a readme for the app here: https://github.com/electricjay/django-foxycart

You need to have it listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'foxycart',
    ...
)
```

And you need to define the URL to your foxycart with `FOXYCART_URL`:

```
FOXYCART_URL = "http://foo"
```

Although in the readme it looks like the value has changed to: FOXYCART_API_URL, but maybe you are using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a FOXYCART_URL attribute in the `settings.py` file found at either the top of the project directory tree (pre-1.4) or in the app that shares the same name as the project (1.4+).